# How can I call external array inside of foreach loop that is dealing with another array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an external array that cointains data (station and time).
I want to compare if that data already exists in my database, if it doesnt exist insert that particular station or if the time isnt equal to the time in a database update it. I just dont know how to call external data in foreach loop where I am looping database data, so I will leave insert and update part for now aside.

This is the code that I have:

```
<?php
// all database parameters
require_once("config.php");

// main array usually contains up to around 40 arrays
$data_array = array(
                array("time"=>"2016-07-01 19:00:00", "name_station"=>"RC Bilogora", "type_station"=>"1", "longitude"=>"17.162", "latitude"=>"45.882", "temperature"=>"28.8"),
                array("time"=>"2016-07-01 19:00:00", "name_station"=>"Bjelovar", "type_station"=>"1", "longitude"=>"16.869", "latitude"=>"45.910", "temperature"=>"28.6"),
                array("time"=>"2016-07-01 19:00:00", "name_station"=>"Crikvenica", "type_station"=>"1",  "longitude"=>"14.689", "latitude"=>"45.173", "temperature"=>"28.0")
                );

// print $data_array
echo "Data from external array";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data_array);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<hr>";

try {
        // connect to the database
        $dbh = new PDO('pgsql:host='.DB_HOST. ';port=' .DB_PORT. ';dbname=' .DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

        // start transaction
        $dbh->beginTransaction();

        // query
        $sql_select = "SELECT station, time FROM vwstationmeasurmentdva";
        $stmt_select = $dbh->prepare($sql_select);
        $stmt_select->execute();
        $result_select = $stmt_select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        // print results from sql for view stationmeasurment
        echo "Station and time from database captured with FETCH ASSOC";
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result_select);
        echo "</pre>";
        echo "<hr>";

        $number_of_rows = count($result_select);

        // FOREACH loop
        $result_vwstationmeasurment_select_array = array ();
        foreach($result_select as $row) {
            $station_name_db = $row['station'];
            $time_db = $row['time'];
            echo $station_name_db . "<br>";
            echo $time_name_db . "<br>";

            // PROBLEM: I DONT KNOW HOW TO CALL $station_name AND $time BEFORE THIS IF STATEMENT SO I CAN DO THE IF STATEMENT
            if ($station_name_db != $station_name OR empty($station_name_db)){
               echo "This station is not in a database or there are no data for stations in a database at all so insert that station";
            } elseif ($time_db != $time){
               echo "Time from external data is not equal to the time in a database so update time in a database";
            }

            $result_vwstationmeasurment_select_array[] =($row);
    };


        // save transaction
        $dbh->commit();

        // close database connection
        $dbh = null;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
        // cancel the transaciton if something went wrong and write msg about it
        $dbh->rollBack();
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
}
?>
```

print $data_array:

```
Data from external array
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [time] => 2016-07-01 19:00:00
            [name_station] => RC Bilogora
            [type_station] => 1
            [longitude] => 17.162
            [latitude] => 45.882
            [temperature] => 28.8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [time] => 2016-07-01 19:00:00
            [name_station] => Bjelovar
            [type_station] => 1
            [longitude] => 16.869
            [latitude] => 45.910
            [temperature] => 28.6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [time] => 2016-07-01 19:00:00
            [name_station] => Crikvenica
            [type_station] => 1
            [longitude] => 14.689
            [latitude] => 45.173
            [temperature] => 28.0
        )

)
```

print $result_select:

Station and time from database captured with FETCH ASSOC

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [station] => RC Bilogora
            [time] => 2016-07-01 16:00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [station] => Bjelovar
            [time] => 2016-07-01 16:00:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [station] => Dubrovnik
            [time] => 2016-07-01 16:00:00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [station] => GospiÄ‡
            [time] => 2016-07-01 16:00:00
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [station] => RC Gorice (kod Nove GradiĹˇke)
            [time] => 2016-07-01 16:00:00
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [station] => RC GradiĹˇte (kod Ĺ˝upanje)
            [time] => 2016-07-01 16:00:00
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [station] => Hvar
            [time] => 2016-07-01 16:00:00
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [station] => Karlovac
            [time] => 2016-07-01 16:00:00
        )
...
```

FOREACH LOOP:

```
RC Bilogora
2016-07-01 16:00:00
Bjelovar
2016-07-01 16:00:00
Dubrovnik
2016-07-01 16:00:00
GospiÄ‡
2016-07-01 16:00:00
RC Gorice (kod Nove GradiĹˇke)
2016-07-01 16:00:00
RC GradiĹˇte (kod Ĺ˝upanje)
2016-07-01 16:00:00
Hvar
2016-07-01 16:00:00
Karlovac
2016-07-01 16:00:00...
```

### **EDITED (@PaulH)**

My way doesnt work at all...can you please suggest me something through the code...

```
try {
        // connect to the database
        $dbh = new PDO('pgsql:host='.DB_HOST. ';port=' .DB_PORT. ';dbname=' .DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

        // start transaction
        $dbh->beginTransaction();

        // EDITED
        foreach($data_array as $row){
                $station_external = $row['name_station'];
                $time_external = $row['time'];
                echo $station_external . "<br>";
                echo $time_external . "<br>";


                // query
                $sql_select = "SELECT station, time FROM vwstationmeasurmentdva";
                $stmt_select = $dbh->prepare($sql_select);
                $stmt_select->execute();
                $result_select = $stmt_select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                // print results from sql for view stationmeasurment
                echo "Station and time from database captured with FETCH ASSOC";
                //echo "<h2>Ovo su stanica i vrijeme dohvaceni iz baze podataka samo uz pomoc print_r nakon FETCH ASSOC</h2>";
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($result_select);
                echo "</pre>";
        } // THE END OF EDIT

                // save transaction
                $dbh->commit();

                // close database connection
                $dbh = null;

} catch (PDOException $e) {
                // cancel the transaciton if something went wrong and write msg about it
                $dbh->rollBack();
                print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
                die();
}
```

This prints:

```
RC Bilogora
2016-07-01 19:00:00
Station and time from database captured with FETCH ASSOC
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [station] => RC Bilogora
            [time] => 2016-07-01 16:00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [station] => Bjelovar
            [time] => 2016-07-01 16:00:00
        )
...
Bjelovar
2016-07-01 19:00:00
Station and time from database captured with FETCH ASSOC
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [station] => RC Bilogora
            [time] => 2016-07-01 16:00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [station] => Bjelovar
            [time] => 2016-07-01 16:00:00
        )
...
```

Comment: I think you should do it the other way around: for each station in your $data_array: query the database, compare the result and act accordingly (i.e. do nothing, insert or update the database).

Comment: You want to know if `$station_name_db` exists in the `$data_array`?

Comment: @ spirit the other way around!

Comment: @ PaulH thanks for a suggestion, I will try to do that!

Comment: @PaulH I have tried something, but it  doesnt work, can you please take a look above I have edited some things.

Comment: Great. Now refine your sql statement: `SELECT station, time FROM vwstationmeasurmentdva` should include a `WHERE` using `$station_external` and `$time_external`

Comment: @PaulH thanks! So with that statement I can check if stations  and measurments at certain time from external array exists in a database. How can I do now IF statement based on that so that I can either insert or update data?

Comment: The query should return one or no record. If no record insert. If one record compare time and insert if diff

Comment: I was wrong. You should only query where station, not where time because you need to compare

Comment: @PaulH, you have helped me a lot! I think I am on a right trace thanks to you! I will update my question as an answer later!

Comment: I"m glad you manage. You can post a separate answer to your own question. That seems more appropriate than change the question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is based on the comments of PaulH to who I extend my gratitude. Nice way of teaching somebody, thank you for the given instructions.

```
    foreach($data_array as $row){
            // station name from array
            $station_name = $row['name_station'];

            // query
            $sql_select = "SELECT station FROM vwstationmeasurmentdva WHERE station='$station_name'";
            $stmt_select = $dbh->prepare($sql_select);
            $stmt_select->execute();
            $result_select = $stmt_select->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $number_of_rows = count($result_select);
            if ($number_of_rows < 1){
                    echo " <br> Station doesn't exist in a database, we have to insert it. <br>";
            } else {
                    echo " <br> Station does exist in a database, so we will update the measurments. <br>";
           }
    }
```